# Can Sphinx autodoc document namespace.module without documenting namespace?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

The code base I'm working with is structured under a `namespace`. I'm responsible for `namespace.my_project`, but I depend on various other modules from `namespace`. Is there any way to tell Sphinx (with autodoc) to document `namespace.my_project`, but ignore everything directly under `namespace`?

I've tried adding exactly the module I want to `index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
    namespace.my_project
```

This shows up fine in the final documentation, but during compilation I still get a lot of warnings from members of `namespace` that I don't have control over.

Comment: What are the warnings about? Can't you just ignore them?

Comment: Because the other projects in the namespace use different sphinx settings I get warnings trying to document them (not confirming to numpydoc, and others). I have to ignore them for now, but I'm not happy about it as it's really hard to spot warnings about my own code..

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many options for this, using the autodoc extension it imports your objects with the normal Python importing rules.

> [sphinx.ext.autodoc – Include documentation from docstrings](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html)
>
> This extension can import the modules you are documenting, and pull in documentation from docstrings in a semi-automatic way.

So, you would have to selectivly write your `.rst` files using autodoc directives that import only what you want. From your example, assuming `my_project` is structured as a package, this could be relativly easy, you would write:

```
.. automodule:: namespace.my_project
```

or lets say you have 2 different packages within `my_project`

```
.. automodule:: namespace.my_project.my_package1

.. automodule:: namespace.my_project.my_package2
```

Basically you've imported only the modules/objects from the project that interest you. Then in the `.. toctree::` directive you would include only `.rst` files that have these carefully chosen directives.

This does have a few drawbacks however, all the objects in the namespace that you don't explicitly document would not be included in the index and would not be cross-referenceable (unless you created empty `.rst` declarations with [domain directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-python-domain)). They would, however, be rendered textually without links and assuming there are no underlying Python errors the documentation would build normally without warnings.